# Only specific file show ( eg PDF) before uploading in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scenario where I am only allowed to upload specific file types, e.g. PDF.
I don't want to validate the type at form submit time. I need to verify the type is OK before selecting the file. Keep in mind the `accept` attribute is not supported in HTML5.

I have two options in mind.

1. Only acceptable file types should be available choices.
2. If possible, trigger a Javascript function after selecting a file. Opposite of onclick.

This is how I tried to validate on submit:

```html
<form name="fileupload" onsubmit="return file_upload();">
    <table align="center" bgcolor="#8080FF" height="100">
        <tr>
            <th> Fileupload:</th>
            <td> <input type="file" name="word" id="word" > </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="submit" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function file_upload()
    {
        var imgpath = document.getElementById('word').value;
        if (imgpath == "") {
            alert("upload your word file");
            document.file.word.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // code to get File Extension..
            var arr1 = new Array;
            arr1 = imgpath.split("\\");
            var len = arr1.length;
            var img1 = arr1[len - 1];
            var filext = img1.substring(img1.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            // Checking Extension
            if (filext == "doc" || filext == "docx") {
                alert("File has been upload correctly")
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Invalid File Format Selected");
                document.form.word.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```